# Error when running do/while continuerequest for SSJS API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ssjs

I need to pull a comprehensive unsub list and automate this process daily, and unfortunately the data view _Subscribers only goes back 6 months so a query is out.  The best solution I have found to accomplish this is through an API call to the Subscriber Object.

I built this using SSJS and a do/while with ContinueRequest to go beyond the 2500 limit, but after around 8500 records it errors and I have no idea why.  The error message, as usual, is completely useless and just comes back with "An error has occurred".

Could this be a time-out issue?  We are looking at around 88,000 unsub records that will be pulled with probably around 1mil or more total records in this MID.

Below is a sample of my SSJS API call:

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

    var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "Subscriber");

    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "SubscriberKey");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Status");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "UnsubscribedDate");

    var sfp = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp, "Property", "Status");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp, "SimpleOperator", "equals");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(sfp, "Value", "Unsubscribed");

    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "Filter", sfp);

    do { 
        var results = [0,0];
        var rows = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr, results);

        var runstatus = results[0];
        var requestId = results[1];

        if (rows != null) {

            for (var i in rows) {
                var subkey = rows[i].SubscriberKey;
                var status = rows[i].Status;
                var unsubdate = rows[i].UnsubscribedDate;

                Platform.Variable.SetValue("@subkey",subkey);       
                Platform.Variable.SetValue("@status", status);
                Platform.Variable.SetValue("@unsubdate",unsubdate);
                Platform.Variable.SetValue("@i",i);

            </script>

            <script runat="server" language="ampscript">

               UpsertDE("MYDataExtension", 1, "EmailAddress", @subkey, "Status", @status, "UnsubscribedDate", @unsubdate)

            </script>    

            <script runat="server">    
            } 
        }
        rr.ContinueRequest = requestId;

    } while (runstatus == "MoreDataAvailable")

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer from SFMC support - apparently some of my Subscribers have the status of Unsubscribed, but have a null value inside of the UnsubscribedDate field, which is not an acceptable input inside of an UPSERT to a date/time field.  So by changing the date/time field to a text field, it went through without issue.