# Marketing cloud grabbing all zips for displaying on a cloud page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage

I have a data extension that holds ~200k records each record has a zip code associated with it.

On my cloud page, I would like to display all of the UNIQUE zips as selectable options.

I have a solution in SSJS that allows only up to 2500 due to limitations of rows.retrieve()

is there anyway to grab the rest of them?

my code if interested

```
<script runat="server">
        Platform.Load("core","1");

        var makeArrhold =  DataExtension.Init("somedataextid");
        var makearrr2 = makeArrhold.Rows.Retrieve();

        var makeholder= [];

        for (var j = 0; j < makearrr2.length; j++)  {
          makeholder.push(makearrr2[j].Make_TXT);
        }

        var unqmakeholder = [];

        var negcheck;

        for(var b=0; makeholder.length > b; b++){

          negcheck = -1;

          for(var i=0; unqmakeholder.length > i; i++){


            negcheck = unqmakeholder[i].indexOf(makeholder[b]);

            if(negcheck != -1){
              negcheck = testresult; 
            }

          } 

          if(negcheck == -1){
            unqmakeholder.push(makeholder[b]); 

          }

        }


        Write("<UL>");
        for (var j = 0; j < unqmakeholder.length; j++)  {
          Write("<LI>" + unqmakeholder[j] + "</LI>");
        }
        Write("</UL>");



      </script>
```

this works to grab the unique values but will break once records reach over 2500'

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest to create a data extension with all the unique zipcodes from your original DE. This can be built with Automation Studio and appropriate Query Activity. Let's call this new DE *uniquezips*

```
Set @zipcodes = 
LookupOrderedRows('uniquezips',DataExtensionRowCount('uniquezips'),'zip ASC','include','1')
```

You need to set a column with a consistent value across all rows (e.g. *include*), to overcome the need for a condition in LookupOrderedRows. This can be done in the query building *uniquezips*

You can also use [this approach by Adam Spriggs](https://sprignaturemoves.com/de-duplicate-rows-ampscript/), to deduplicate your rows directly in AmpScrip.

If SSJS is a hard requirement, there is a well-described solution [here on StackExchange.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/167801/ssjs-retrieve-dataextension-rows-by-retrieverequest)